# Which exception should be thrown when a required property of a parameter object is null

Tags: c#, exception, null

I use parameter objects to encapsulate the parameters that are passed to my business rules.  The rule is created using a context parameter, which may then be modified, then at a later time the rule is executed.  Some of the properties of this object are required, otherwise the method would throw a `NullReferenceException`.  However, if I throw an `ArgumentNullException`, I get a warning saying that the parameter name does not match one of my parameters. What would be the appropriate exception for this situation?

```
public class GetAttributes : BusinessRuleBase 
{
    private readonly IGetAttributesContext _context;


    public GetAttributes(IGetAttributesContext context)
    {
        _context = context;
    }

    public override void Execute()
    {
        if (_context.AttributeModel == null)
        {
            //Exception would be thrown here
        }
        _context.Attributes = _context.AttributeModel
                                      .DoSomething(_context.EntityType);
    }
}
```

Comment: I suggest using Code Contracts instead. `ArgumentNullException` isn't really useful, since any `catch` for that type is most likely indicative of a bug.

Comment: Many people are of the opinion that you should never throw an exception of a type that can also be raised automatically by the system - and `NullReferenceException` is one of these.

Comment: Why not `InvalidOperationException`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you are using Code Contracts and you are willing to publicly expose a `HasAttributeModel` property, I recommend

```
Contract.Requires(this.HasAttributeModel);
```

Otherwise, you should throw a custom exception that derives from [`InvalidOperationException`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.invalidoperationexception.aspx) here. The method that you are trying to execute is not valid given the object's current state. From the documentation:

> The exception that is thrown when a method call is invalid for the object's current state.

Your custom message should say that the instance's `AttributeModel` is `null`.

The larger question is, why are you allowing your instances to be in a state where a method could be invoked on them while the object is in an invalid state? You should avoid this, if you can. For example, why isn't `GetAttributes` checking that `context.AttributeModel` is not `null`? You could have

```
Contract.Requires(context.AttributeModel != null);
```

as a precondition for this method. However, there is some danger here in that if someone retains a live reference to the referrent of the parameter `context`, they could destroy the state since you maintain a reference via the private variable `_context`. Be aware of this, and avoid it if you can.

Comment: The custom message should say that the instance's *`IGetAttributesContext`'s* `AttributeModel` is `null`.

Comment: The idea is that the values of the properties of the context can be affected by other business rules before the current rule is executed. This allows another rule to set something like the EntityType or AccountModel before this rule is executed.  I agree with InvalidOperationException in this case, since the context parameter is part of the state of my object.

Comment: @Ryan Gross: That's kind of gross.

Comment: I also agree that using a code contract would be a better option, but we aren't using them in our project.

Comment: I disagree with idea of using standard exceptions for anything that one will expect to catch and handle.  If it is expected that code will be e.g. performing queries in response to user requests that may or may not be valid, it's far more useful to have an exception that indicates that the requested query was invalid but system state is otherwise presumably fine, than to have an ArgumentException or InvalidOperationException which could mean anything, and may or may not indicate a serious problem.

Comment: Those who would throw a standard exception for something that should be handled specially violate guideline #2.  It may be good to derive one's exception from InvalidOperationException, rather than from Exception, but if one simply throws InvalidOperationException, then anyone who wants to catch it will risk catching exceptions resulting from other causes.

Comment: @supercat: The client of this code higher up could and should catch the `InvalidOperationException` and wrap it in a custom exception indicating the query is not valid.

Comment: @Jason: How should the that higher-up code distinguish the InvalidOperationException caused by this expected scenario, from one occurring in some other, possibly unexpected, scenario? Note that the Framework Design Guidelines were intended for the AUTHORS of the framework, not CONSUMERS. If the consumers of one's code are expected to have access to the source, the design methodology should be different than if they don't. When catching an exception, it's useful to know all the ways it might be thrown. If it's a custom exception, one can know. Otherwise one really can't.

Comment: @supercat: No, those guidelines are not just for the .NET framework, if that is what you are saying. However, I'm leaning towards agreeing with you on your original point. I need to think a little more.

Comment: @supercat: Upon further thought, I agree with you.

Answer (score 1):

If you think someone may want to catch this particular exception and handle it in a different way from typical exceptions, write your own exception class.

Ideally you could get fail-fast behavior by checking this property in the (poorly-named) `GetAttributes` method. In that case, if you're not using your own custom exception type, I would throw an `ArgumentException`.

If it doesn't make sense to check this property early on, and you still want to use a system exception type, Jason is right: use an `InvalidOperationException`.

Comment: The GetAttributes call there was a Constructor (the lack of a return type is a givaway).  I have update the question for more clarity.  I agree that InvalidOperationException is the best option, but I'm not going to accept your answer because you were rude.

Comment: @Ryan Gross: To be fair, the class `GetAttributes` is not named well.

Answer (score 0):

Throw a `NullReferenceException` with your custom description, or create own custom exception.

`InvalidArgumentException` says that the argument is invalid, but in your case there is no argument and for beeing invalid or valid it has to be not null.

Comment: No, he didn't dereference a `null` object reference.

Answer (score 0):

You should use your custom exceptions to be sure that you really catch your exception, not the system-generated one.

Comment: No, there is already a perfectly valid derivative of `Exception` in the framework: `InvalidOperationException`. Creating custom exceptions in this case goes against the framework design guidelines.